# I want to add an custom extension(trainingcommercewebservices ) using ycommercewebservices template Could any body please guide me

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am using SAP E COMMERCE SUITE CXCOMM210500P_12-70005661.ZIP
I have done Spartacus setup
I have generated custom extensions using ant modulegen

But I can't see any extension like trainingcommercewebservices extension.

So I have added a custom extension trainingcommercewebservices based up on ycommercewebservices extension using `ant extgen` command.
I have done below changes

added new extension in localextensions.xml

```
<extension name='trainingcommercewebservices' />
```

removed

```
<extension name='commercewebservices' />
```

from localextensions.xml
(I couldn't find any extension like

```
<extension name='ycommercewebservices' />
```

in localextensons.xml.

---

I have done `ant clean all` and started server

I have tried with url https://localhost:9002/trainingcommercewebservices/v2/swagger-ui.html and I found result like

404 - Page does not exist
We’re sorry, but this page does not exist.

I have tried this url https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/swagger-ui.html and found error
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<errors>
<error>
<type>UnsatisfiedDependencyError</type>
</error>
</errors>
```

I have tried to access storeront with url http://localhost:4200/

Got error

[angular storefront error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o58a2.png)

when I am trying to access swagger url I am getting below error in console

**Sep 21, 2023 1:53:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [springmvc-v2] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Hybris/2105/hybris/bin/modules/web-services-commons/webservicescommons/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Hybris/2105/hybris/bin/modules/web-services-commons/webservicescommons/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.config.WebConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Hybris/2105/hybris/bin/modules/web-services-commons/webservicescommons/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.config.WebConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.v2.config.WebConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getCurrentTenant(Registry.java:811)
at de.hybris.platform.util.Config.getInt(Config.java:243)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.getMethodPriorityValue(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:150)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.registerOverriddenMapping(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:226)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.detectOverriddenMappings(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:215)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.initOverridenRequestMappings(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:177)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.initHandlerMethods(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
... 70 more
Sep 21, 2023 1:53:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [springmvc-v2]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getCurrentTenant(Registry.java:811)
at de.hybris.platform.util.Config.getInt(Config.java:243)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.getMethodPriorityValue(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:150)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.registerOverriddenMapping(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:226)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.detectOverriddenMappings(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:215)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.initOverridenRequestMappings(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:177)
at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.request.mapping.handler.CommerceHandlerMapping.initHandlerMethods(CommerceHandlerMapping.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)**

Pease help me to add trainingcommercewebservices extension which is based up on ycommercewebservices to my project
Note: I have already installed trainngocc extension, but I want to add trainingcommercewebservices  to my project.

Comment: I can't see  ycommercewebservices extension in my localextensions.xml.

Comment: The error here comes from web context startup and is caused by the fact that the master tenant did not start for some reason: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant()".
I think that you need to check startup log for error messages that appear earlier than this one that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

OCC layer in SAP Commerce contains these main building blocks:

- *commercewebservices* - This is a web extension that bootstraps the whole OCC machinery, basically this contains all the Spring web configuration with controllers, filters, etc.
- *ycommercewebservices* - This is a template that was once meant to be used to create custom versions of the *commercewebservices* - this is deprecated and should not be used for extending OCC
- *yocc* - This is a template for any OCC extensions that are loaded additionally by the main *commercewebservices* extension. You should be using this template to generate your own extensions to the OCC layer. See this for details: [Creating an OCC Extension for OCC Web Services](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/3476714bba0b4cb9b3eb58c270e44439/8ef2d8d7baf1443dbed3affb49606adf.html?locale=en-US)

You can learn about the OCC extension approach here: [OCC Extension-based Architecture](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/3476714bba0b4cb9b3eb58c270e44439/d46d19516961438f8939718e87ed787b.html?locale=en-US).

When you have created a new extension from *ycommercewebservices* and added it to *localextensions.xml* then you have created another OCC main extension alongside of *commercewebservices*. I'm guessing (since you did not provide any error message) that these two extensions are in conflict and one of them cannot start.

There are two ways to go:

1. Preferred way: leave *commercewebservices* as it is, remove the extension *ycommercewebservices* and move any custom code to extensions generated based on *yocc*
2. Deprecated but theoretically should work: remove *commercewebservices* from *localextensions.xml* and leave your custom extension generated based on *ycommercewebservices*. Keep in mind though that this is not a future-proof approach e.g. you will not benefit from upgrades to *commercewebservices* provided by SAP in this case

Comment: https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/swagger-ui.html

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<errors>
<error>
<type>UnsatisfiedDependencyError</type>
</error>
</errors>